# Variable not passing correctly in TSQL Query

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, parameters

I'm stumped on this one. Probably an easy problem, but I can't wrap my head around this.

I have a simple query where I union the result set together so I can manipulate data based on different criteria.

I have a parameter in place so this can eventually become a SSRS report.

Here's my condensed query...

There are 3 params: StartDate, EndDate, and Supplier.

StartDate and EndDate are data type date, and Supplier is char(7)

When I run the query with the param set as '1040', I get no results

```
DECLARE @STARTDATE AS DATE
DECLARE @ENDDATE AS DATE
DECLARE @SUPPLIER AS CHAR

SET @STARTDATE = '2013-12-01'
SET @ENDDATE = '2013-12-31'
SET @SUPPLIER = '1040'

SELECT *
  FROM InvMovements AS AA
  JOIN InvMaster AS BB
    ON AA.StockCode = BB.StockCode
  JOIN ApSupplier AS CC
    ON CC.Supplier = BB.Supplier
 WHERE MovementType = 'I'
   AND TrnType = 'T'
   AND TrnQty < 0
   AND Warehouse = 'ZC'
   AND CC.Supplier = @SUPPLIER 
   AND EntryDate BETWEEN @STARTDATE AND @ENDDATE
```

Now when I change the WHERE clause to show any suppliers like the parameter (CC.Supplier LIKE '%' +  @SUPPLIER + '%')  , I get these results

```
Supplier    StockCode   Warehouse   EntryDate   TrnType    TrnQty
1000        317012      ZC          2013-12-06  T          18.000
1040        320062      ZC          2013-12-06  T           8.000
```

We only have 4 character suppliers.

If I manually set the supplier as CC.Supplier = '1040' I get the exact result set that I'm looking for. I've tried it in SSRS and I'm getting the same results.

Any ideas? This seems like such a dumb problem, but I can't seem to figure out why this is happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do this:

```
DECLARE @SUPPLIER AS CHAR
```

then your variable is **exactly one character** long.

So when you do an assigment

```
SET @SUPPLIER = '1040'
```

you really just stored `1` in that variable.

You need to give your `CHAR` and `VARCHAR` **an explicit length** when you define them! You should get in the habit of doing this always - when you declare a variable, when you declare a parameter to a stored procedure or function, or when you use `CHAR` or `VARCHAR` in a `CAST` or `CONVERT` situation - **define the length!**

```
DECLARE @SUPPLIER AS CHAR(4)
SET @SUPPLIER = '1040'
```

then it works as expected.

Comment: You're kidding me.....haha! Worked great. That makes perfect sense. Appreciate the help on this!